# Vega-lite limiting the number of ticks with ordinal type

Tags: vega-lite

I have used an example of Vega-lite bar chart in which I have a Major Genre on x-axis and y-axis is showing the count.

Below is the vega-lite configuration:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.json",
  "description": "A dashboard with cross-highlighting.",
  "data": {"url": "data/movies.json"},
  "width": 330,
  "height": 120,
  "mark": "bar",
  "selection": {"pts": {"type": "single", "encodings": ["x"]}},
  "encoding": {
    "x": {
      "field": "Major Genre",
      "type": "ordinal",
      "axis": {"labelAngle": 0, "labelOverlap": "parity"}
    },
    "y": {"aggregate": "count"},
    "color": {
      "condition": {"selection": "pts", "value": "steelblue"},
      "value": "grey"
    }
  }
}
```

In this, I have used `labelOverlap` config in x-axis to avoid overlapping of labels, so with this now am having limited number of label names. I want to reduce the number of ticks of x-axis which should be equal to the labels. I tried using `tickCount` config but it seems to work on quantitative and temporal types of field. Also when we use temporal then the date fields show limited no. of labels and ticks. So this type of behaviour is what I want to achieve with nominal and ordinal type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I'm aware of to reduce the number of ticks in a nominal or ordinal axis is to either set `"ticks": false` to hide *all* ticks, or to explicitly set the visible ticks using the `"values"` entry. Here is an example of the latter ([open in editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJghgLhIFygK4CcA29zQgegLYHsA3ASwFMBnAOgCtz8A7EAXwBoQB3YsKAC3gGZ+ABjY9SxAOY8o8AIwAmESFwRkAawwAjVSDblSqUgGMoxBvFAAHKOQsgoAT0ukM5YvQmHdIUvSP4wdwlbOABtEAAPEABdJlYfPwCguyiEEAAzMlQwDABZCGp8ZAACAHFfZBc2R2cMIsD6CHQ2CAjiENBUCE0DAEEPLzglLp7UAHlCUjQISwxLVWJHb0ImxAp4UPpEVFQ2AGF8XFIwB28ACSLkIu8AdQooKcZY+NO0iAkJSoloFzgQf0Q9Bk8X8qGuaX89ECpnMaX0hhMZkYf2stjYK1Qa1cDwMmkxLniGKxf0+pFOcSYQA)):

```
{
  "data": {"url": "data/movies.json"},
  "width": 330,
  "height": 120,
  "mark": "bar",
  "selection": {"pts": {"type": "single", "encodings": ["x"]}},
  "encoding": {
    "x": {
      "field": "Major Genre",
      "type": "ordinal",
      "axis": {
        "labelAngle": 0,
        "labelOverlap": "parity",
        "values": [null, "Comedy", "Horror", "Western"]
      }
    },
    "y": {"aggregate": "count"},
    "color": {
      "condition": {"selection": "pts", "value": "steelblue"},
      "value": "grey"
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't want to hide the ticks, so using values is a good option. But, then I have to hard code the axis data. Instead, of hard coding it if the ticks would have appeared dynamically then that would have worked. Still, I appreciate your help.

Comment: I agree it's not convenient, but hard-coding is currently the only possible way to hide some (not all) ticks with a nominal or ordinal scale.

Answer (score 0):

I had to create another layer with x-axis in which am hiding the label names and added another data object which will have some dummy records. This is not a proper approach but it seems to satisfy my use case. So the extra layer will do the job of showing the ticks no matter the main data labels.
Below is the modified vega-lite config:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.json",
  "description": "A dashboard with cross-highlighting.",
  "data": {"url": "data/movies.json"},
  "width": 320,
  "height": 120,
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": "bar",
      "selection": {"pts": {"type": "single", "encodings": ["x"]}},
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "field": "Major Genre",
          "type": "ordinal",
          "axis": {
            "labelAngle": 0,
            "labelOverlap": "parity",
            "ticks": false,
            "labelPadding": 10
          }
        },
        "y": {"aggregate": "count"},
        "color": {
          "condition": {"selection": "pts", "value": "steelblue"},
          "value": "grey"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": "text",
      "data": {
        "values": [
          {"Major Genre": "a"},
          {"Major Genre": "b"},
          {"Major Genre": "c"},
          {"Major Genre": "d"}
        ]
      },
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "field": "Major Genre",
          "type": "ordinal",
          "axis": {"labels": false, "orient": "bottom", "title": null}
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "resolve": {"axis": {"x": "independent"}, "scale": {"x": "independent"}}
}
```